# unable to clear the previous data before apply new data in web api using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm working on asp.net 4 web api project

i'm appending data to `span` using following code:

Using model I'm showing info about all groups

When I clicked on `menu's` I passed `Id` and depending upon that fetching new values

But when I click on new `Id` I'm `unable to clear prev data`

It is only `appending new data with Prev`

```
 $.getJSON(
                    "api/groupvalues/" + id,
                    function (data) {

                        $.each(data, function (index, value) {

                            debugger;
                            if (value.Id != undefined) {

 $("#GroupTemplate").prev().remove();​​​​​​​​​ //UNABLE TO REMOVE PREV DATA

$("#GroupTemplate").tmpl(value).appendTo(".span9"); // IT IS DIRECTLY APPENDING DATA WITH PREV ONE
                            }
                        });    



      <div class="span9">
                    <div class="row">
                        <section id="projects">

                             <!-- End FORACH -->
                        </section>

                    </div>
                </div>

<script id="GroupTemplate" type="text/html">
                        <ul id="thumbs">
                            <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                            <li class="item-thumbs span3 Dhol">
                                <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->                                

                                <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                                <img src="../images/img/work/thumbs/image-01.jpg" alt="">
                           <div style="margin-top:5px;">
                             <div class="verifybtngrp"><span class="font-icon-ok-sign" title="verified account"></span></div>
            <h4 class="profile-namegrp"><a href="#"></a>${Name}</h4>

            <p class="profile-description">
            <span class="font-icon-map-marker-2"></span>${Area}<br />
            <span class="font-icon-music"></span>${Name}<br />
            </p></div> </li>
                            <!-- End Item Project -->
                        </ul>                        
                        </script>
```

> Even I tried all `(".span9").html('');` `(".span9").remove();` but No Luck

Comment: Can you show your markup?

Comment: @ChrisHardie updated my question please check

Comment: `$(".span9").html( $("#GroupTemplate").empty().tmpl(value) )`

Comment: @adeneo you mean to say I used like this 
//first clear                            `$(".span9").html($("#GroupTemplate").empty().tmpl(value))`
             //then append new value               `$("#GroupTemplate").tmpl(value).appendTo(".span9");`

Comment: No, if you're trying to clear the element of content on each insertion, you shouldn't be using append() at all, as it does exactly that, appends the content. You want to replace the content, and should be using **only** the line I wrote above.

Comment: Looking at it now, you should probably remove the empty() call, as that would remove the template -> `$(".span9").html( $("#GroupTemplate").tmpl(value) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did like following

`$(".span9").html($("#GroupTemplate").removeData());`

Answer (score 0):

By the sound of it, you want to clear an element, and then append new data inside it. If that's the case, then instead of removing a node from the DOM, just clear the markup of the node of interest:

```
 $(".span9").html('');
```

Comment: I tried all `(".span9").html('');` `(".span9").remove();` but No Luck